# Exception instead of Compiler Error

Tags: java

I expected this program to give me Compile error but it compiled successfully and I got a runtime exception while running it.

```
class substr11
{

public static void main(String args[])
{

String s = "abcde";

System.out.println(s.substring(1,-1));

}


}
```

The compiler error should be able to parse (string is initialized in the body itself) and find out that this string operation would result in compile error right ?.
Can someone tell me why it did not throw compile error ?

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String ind
ex out of range: -2
        at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
        at substr11.main(substr11.java:9)

Comment: Because the compiler isn't a comprehensive static analysis tool?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I just want to know if it is purpose or not. May I missunderstood his question cauze I thought the outofbounds is thrown cauze he use -1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Compile error* is when the compiler **can't** compile the code (Syntax error, missing symbols etc..).

That's not the case in your program, you're passing two `int`s to [String#substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) as expected, and you're not missing anything (No missing classes, brackets are OK, semicolons are as supposed), so why should the compiler care?

You get an *Exception* if the code **compiled** but crashed due to some *Exception* (like [ArrayIndexOutOfBounds](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)).

Answer (score 1):

The compiler never parses or optimizes into method calls. Even though a substring operation may be invalid and have hardwired arguments, it doesn't matter since it won't parse the entire method call.

That call could potentially have side effects, or only throw runtime exceptions under complex sets of conditions that could include the instance, static variables, and even the choice of libraries.

A compile error could include invalid syntax, but not things like this. The method call is valid. Perhaps a certain string could take this set of parameters for its substring method. The compiler won't perform complex analysis on that string.

If it did that, compiles would take forever, and many, many bugs would arise.

Answer (score 1):

There is no compile time error in your code. The call to `substring()` is taking two int's, which is a valid invocation of the [`substring` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29).

The compiler doesn't inspect the String contents, so it doesn't see that this will throw an exception at runtime.

As far as the compiler sees, the `s` variable is only assumed to be a `String`, there are no assumptions on its contents. In this case it has been assigned a constant value, but it could have been something imponderable such as a database query result, or anything else. The same applies to the `int` arguments of the function.

Summing up, as hexafraction pointed out in his answer, the compiler doesn't perform complex analysis on the input. The developer is responsible of doing the necessary checks on the input in order to avoid runtime or checked exceptions, or catch them accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't know what will be the result of the operation. He know that `s.substring()` needs 2 int parameters and he ensures that the call is correct (`s.substring(1,-1)` has to int parameters).

Answer (score 0):

Spare some time to read the Spec  [JLS#11.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2)

> Compile-Time Checking of Exceptions
>
> The Java programming language requires that a program contains handlers for checked exceptions which can result from execution of a method or constructor. For each checked exception which is a possible result, the throws clause for the method (§8.4.6) or constructor (§8.8.5) must mention the class of that exception or one of the superclasses of the class of that exception (§11.2.3).
>
> This compile-time checking for the presence of exception handlers is designed to reduce the number of exceptions which are not properly handled. The checked exception classes (§11.1.1) named in the throws clause are part of the contract between the implementor and user of the method or constructor. The throws clause of an overriding method may not specify that this method will result in throwing any checked exception which the overridden method is not permitted, by its throws clause, to throw (§8.4.8.3).

And the exception hirarchy

```
java.lang.Object
  java.lang.Throwable
    java.lang.Exception
     java.lang.RuntimeException
       java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
         java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

The exception occurs at run time not at compiler time.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix up compiler job, which is in nutshell just translation your code into low-level instructions, and code execution. In your case program should invoke a lot of sub-functions to "understand" that there is a logic error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone tell me why it did not throw compile error?

Because it is not a compilation error, and Java programmers (and their managers!) entitled to *rely* on this not being a compilation error!!

In another world, the Java language *could have been* specified to require (or allow) the compiler to attempt to evaluate that `substring` call, and flag it as an error.

However, in this world, a Java compiler is only *allowed* to do that for "constant expression" (as specified in the [JLS 15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)).  Any expression that includes a method call is not a "constant expression" according to the spec.  So, in reality, the `substring` call *must* be evaluated at runtime and is *must* give you a runtime exception.

---

So why is Java designed this way?

You'd need to ask the Java designers ...

... but I think it is a combination of two things:

- The Java 1.0 language had to be released early or it would miss the market opportunity.
- Then there was overarching requirement for backwards compatibility ... so that old Java programs would continue to work as the language evolved.